# For Loop Implementation + RandInt

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

Trying to do this python code that generates random numbers to do addition and multiplication operations based on the user input. I need help on how to run each function only five times and then go back to the menu again. Thank you so much :(( Also, everytime the answer prints, it generates "None" below the line. How do I get rid of that?

```
    import random 

    ## def of menu: options_menu function ##
    def options_menu():
      print ("a > Addition")
      print ("m > Multiplication")
      print ("q > Quit")
   ## end of options_menu function ##

   ## def of addition function ##
   def addition_option():
     int_a = random.randint(1,100)
     int_b = random.randint(1,9)
     addition_operation = int(input (str(int_a) + " + " + str(int_b) + " = "))
     addition_result = int_a + int_b

     if addition_operation == addition_result:
       print ("Correct")
     else: 
       print ("Incorrect. The correct answer is " + str(addition_result))
    ## end of addition function ##

    ## def of multiplication function ##
    def multiplication_option():
      int_a = random.randint(1,100)
      int_b = random.randint(1,9)
      multiplication_operation = int(input (str(int_a) + " x " + str(int_b) + " = "))
      multiplication_result = int_a * int_b

      if multiplication_operation == multiplication_result:
        print ("Correct")
      else:
        print ("Incorrect. The correct answer is " + str(multiplication_result))

    ## end of multiplication function ##

    ## def of quit function ##
    def quit_option():
       print ("Good bye!")
       return quit_option()
    ## end of quit function ##

    ##### MAIN PROGRAM ####

    #print the menu
    options_menu()
    user_choice = input("Enter command (a/m/q): ")

    while True: 

      if user_choice == "a":
        print(addition_option())

      elif user_choice == "m":
        print(multiplication_option())

      elif user_choice == "q":
        print(quit_option())
```

Comment: `def quit_option():
       print ("Good bye!")
       return quit_option()` infinite recursion

Comment: your functions don't return anything. so they return `None`